# TabLayout not showing

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a translation app that has different screens for categories of words. User able to swipe left and right to see different categories or just tap on the category tabs. However, my tabs are not showing up. I have checked every details that are related to tabs to no avail, please help me!

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/tan_background"
    tools:context="com.example.android.miwok.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.android.miwok;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ViewPager mViewPager;
    CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
}
```

CategoryAdapter.java

```
package com.example.android.miwok;


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;


public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new NumbersFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FamilyFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ColorsFragment();
            case 3:
                return new PhrasesFragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
               return mContext.getString(R.string.category_numbers);
            case 1:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.category_family);
            case 2:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.category_colors);
            case 3:
                return mContext.getString(R.string.category_phrases);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably height of ViewPager is covering whole screen as it is set to match_parent

Comment: try adding `android:layout_weight="1"` to your `ViewPager`.

Comment: Your answer is correct but i was trying to show the tabs on top, i got the order of the layout wrong, sorry for not clarifying enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not about 100% sure, but I would suggest you move your `TabLayout` above your `ViewPager` because the `ViewPager` has the height of `match_parent`.

Regards
Tarik

Comment: hi devlen, does that mean that if an item is above the next item which has the height of match_parent, the item above would still be visible and wouldn't get pushed out of screen? Hope you understand my question

Comment: Hey @Jordan, yeah that is correct, therefore there is another concept in android called `ConstraintLayout`. Using constraints is much more precise and it doesn't matter in which order your elements are. For more information consider reading [Build a Resopnse UI with Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Comment: The tutorial i following now still using old layout, i will check out constraint layout once i finished the tutorial, thanks for everything DevLen!

Answer (score 0):

hello Jordan change your activity_main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TabLayoutActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Your answer is correct but i was trying to show the tabs on top, i got the order of the layout wrong, sorry for not clarifying enough. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I got the viewpager and tablayout order reversed, after switching the order the tabs finally showed. Huge thanks to everyone who gave an answer and tried to help.